# Proving that something is a set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm doing problems from my Topology notes. One of them states the following:

Let $A \times B$ (the cartesian product of $A$ and $B$), with $A$ and $B$ sets. Prove that is a set.

How do we prove that something is a set? Not this case in particular, but every 'set' of things.

Is there any axioms that a set have to verify to be a set?

Thanks!

Comment: uhm... how do you define $A\times B$?  If you are referring to the cartesian product *by its very definition* it is a set.  $A\times B:=\{(a,b)~:~a\in A, b\in B\}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I thought exactly this when I saw the exercise, but I'm asked to prove something that I don't know what it is.

Comment: Boy that was an unfortunate typo in the title. lol.

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes! Sorry, I'm writing this from my phon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate a little on the other answer, from the axiom of specification you obtain the empty set; then by the axiom of power set you obtain the set $2 = \{\{\emptyset\},\emptyset\}$. Then, by replacement you obtain the set $\{A,B\}$. By the axiom of union you obtain $A \cup B$. By the axiom of power set you obtain $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(A \cup B))$. Then, from this set you use specification to obtain all elements of the form $\{\{a,b\},\{a\}\}$, where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. This is then the cartesian product, where $\{\{a,b\},\{a\}\}$ is chosen to represent $(a,b)$.

Note, however, that this is axiomatic set theory, which (at this level) has nothing to do with topology. Perhaps it is a mistake in the notes, or you misread, or the notes discuss an "informal" notion of set (something like, "a well-defined collection of elements") and they want you to convince yourself that this is one. (But that would also be weird, because typically a topology course only comes along when you are already quite familiar with the cartesian product.)

Comment: There is no need to use Replacement: [Pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#4._Axiom_of_pairing) gives you $\{A, B\}$ directly.

Comment: Ah, yes. That is simpler, and aligns more closely with the answer I am "commenting" on. I am used to doing ZFC with just the "strongest" axioms, dispensing with pairing because it is superfluous (for the reason above).

Comment: That's a fair point, but note that there's a lot of interesting math around when replacement is *necessary* (not so much for pairing :P); overusing it obscures that, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

First, $\lbrace A, B \rbrace$ exists by the axiom of pairing, so $A\cup B = \bigcup \lbrace A, B \rbrace$ exists by the axiom of union.

The ordered pair $\langle a, b \rangle$ is defined to be $\lbrace \lbrace a \rbrace, \lbrace a, b \rbrace  \rbrace.$

You can see that if $a\in A$ and $b \in B,$ then $\lbrace a \rbrace$ and $\lbrace a, b \rbrace$ are both subsets of $A\cup B,$ so they're both members of $\scr{P}(A \cup B).$  It follows that $\langle a, b \rangle$ is a subset of $\scr{P}\mathrm{(A \cup B),}$ so each $\langle a, b \rangle$ is a member of $\scr{P}(\scr{P}\mathrm{(A \cup B)).}$

Also, you can see that a set $x$ is an ordered pair iff

\begin{align}(\exists a)(\exists b)(\exists c)(\exists d)\Big(&(\forall y)(y \in x \iff (y=c \lor y=d)) \;\land
\\&(\forall y)(y \in c \iff (y=a)) \;\land
\\&(\forall y)(y \in d \iff (y=a \lor y=b))
\\&\!\!\Big).
\end{align}

It follows that we can write

$$A\times B=\lbrace x \in \scr{P}(\scr{P}\mathrm{(A \cup B)) \mid x\text{ is an ordered pair}\rbrace.}$$

So using the axioms of pairing, union, power set, and separation, we've shown that $A\times B$ is a set if $A$ and $B$ are.

Comment: Not sure about the definition of $A \times B$ at the end - it seems you have defined $(A \cup B) \times (A \cup B)$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about Zermelo-Frankel set theory.

> Is there any axioms that a set have to verify to be a set?

No, a set is a *primitive* notion in ZF, meaning it is undefined.

A single look at [the relevant wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Most_common_implementation_.28set_theory.29) answers the question about the Cartesian product of sets:
(Speaking about the [Kuratowski definition or ordered pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski_definition):)

> Therefore, the existence of the Cartesian product of any two sets in ZFC follows from the axioms of pairing, union, power set, and specification.

That is, it is a set by virtue of being constructed out of sets in a way [permitted by the axioms of ZF set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#Axioms). I leave it to you as an exercise of how to apply these specific four axioms to Kuratowski's definition to build the Cartesian product. Drop me a line in the comments if you need a nudge at some point.

Comment: You could explain to him what role each of those axioms have here. Else good answer imo.

Comment: @question Thanks for the input, but I think spelling that all out would waste a great exercise opportunity!

Comment: Looks like there are plenty of other people willing to reexplain a paragraph-and-a-half in wikipedia in case the OP is unwilling to read it anyhow, so I guess we're covered!

Comment: @rschwieb You could say that about much of this site. While you have a point, there's something to be said for self-contained explanations that don't require going somewhere else.  Also, at least in some cases (although maybe not this one!), a new answer might be clearer, or phrased differently, or with a different emphasis, from what you could find elsewhere. (I generally don't read Wikipedia or other sites before posting an answer myself.)

Comment: @MitchellSpector Of course, nobody is going to argue with that, least of all me. I initially just explained my choice to spell things out, and then quipped that the request is satisfied even with my inaction, and now people ought to be happy in any case. I hope what I said wasn't mistaken for arguing that people are wrong to post details. Regards

Comment: Incidentally, I also don't really care if people posting solutions read Wikipedia first. But I think it's a good idea that people asking questions look at it first.

Comment: @rschwieb No argument from me -- thank you for your reply. I had just replied originally because I thought it was an interesting (and amusing) comment that you had made.  There's always a subtle tension between how much to post and how much to let the OP figure out, as well as whether it's worth writing something new to put a different spin on it.